# Counting subsets of a given set

Tags: combinatorics

Could anyone be kind in helping me with this simple question?

What is the number of subsets of $$\{1,2,3,\cdots, n\}$$ containing k elements?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Prove that there are $\binom{n}{k}$ many subsets of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ of size $k$ by induction on $k$.

Comment: @Stefan: induction? That is the _definition_ of $\binom nk$.

Comment: Please confirm: the value of $k$ is fixed (that is, it is given, just like $n$).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Well, I define $\binom{n}{k}= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set equals the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom nk$, by definition of that coefficient. Its value can be computed either additively by Pascal's recursion, or by the multiplicative formula
$$
\binom nk=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-k+1)}{k!}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is the sum of number of ways of choosing $r$ elements from n elements, where $r$ ranges from $0$ to $n$. This is because $r = 0$ is the null set, $k = 1$ is all $nC1$ subsets of cardinality $1$, and so on...

Just imagine yourself picking all subsets of size 0, then size 1, ..., till size n.

This is also the sum of the nth row of Pascal's Triangle, which is also $2^n$.

Permutations do not count, because the order of a set does not matter.

Comment: oops, misread the question haha

Answer (score -2):

The number of subsets in a set is given by $2^n$ where n is the number of elements in the set . It also includes the empty set as a subset.

Comment: The question isn't asking for what's the total number of subsets but rather how many subsets are there with $k$ elements :)